# How do we find an equation of the tangent line to the graph of:

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, tangent-line

Given the point $P(0,1)$, we are asked to find an equation of the tangent line for the following implicit function:
$$y^2+ye^{x}=e^{2x}+1.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: First use implicit differentiation

$$2yy'+y'e^x+ye^x=2e^{2x}.$$

Now, plug in your point $x=0$ and $y=1$ and determine $y'(0)$. If you have found the slope than you can use

$$y = y'(0)(x-x_0)+y_0$$

in which $x_0=0$ and $y_0=1$ gives you the equation of the tangent line.

Comment: Why are we determining y'(0)? Isn't y' the slope?

Comment: $y'(0)$ is the slope for $x=0$.

Comment: When I compute y'(0) I am getting( e^2 = 1/2)Am I doing it right?

Comment: $x=0$ and $y=1$ gives $2y'(0)+y'(0)+1=2 \implies y'(0)=1/3$

Comment: Okay I get it thank you

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of a function is normal to its level curves, so you can use the point-normal form of equation of a line to derive an equation of the tangent at a point $(x_0,y_0)$: $$\nabla f(x_0,y_0)\cdot(x-x_0,y-y_0)=0.\tag{*}$$

Rearrange the implicit equation to get $f:(x,y)\mapsto y^2+ye^x-e^{2x}-1$ and compute its gradient: $$\nabla f = \left(ye^x-2e^{2x},e^x+2y\right).$$ Plugging this and the given point into (*) gives $(-1,3)\cdot(x-0,y-1)=0$, or $x-3y+3=0$.